# Handling Error responses in Retrofit 2.x

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have a retrofit call with GsonConvertorFactory which returns the response as a model (could be a complex model).

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SomeAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
SomeAPI someAPI = retrofit.create(SomeAPI.class);

Call<SomeModel> call = someAPI.getData();
```

Sometimes I have a situation where my api can return failures such as token expired errors which can not be cast to the corresponding model. For example if the token is expired the response would just look like

```
'error' => 'token_expired'
```

Any help in this regard? So I need a way to parse the error and refresh the token. Good design for this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: Thank you very much, it gave me good direction to fix the issue